# Создание потока на c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Как запустить какой-то метод в другом потоке?
ну например хотя бы самое элементарное. есть `label.content = 0`
и при нажатии на кнопку, чтоб каждую секунду значение `label` было +1 и чтоб программа не зависала, а это делалось в потоке...
Да, возможно нубский вопрос, в инете находил подобное, но чего-то не работает....
Если можете, напишите пожалуйста пример кода....

Comment: вам нужен не поток, а таймер, к сожалению не в курсе как дела с таймерами в WPF

Comment: не, это я к примеру.....мне именно поток нужен, чтоб действия,котор занимают много времени выполнялись фоново....

Comment: Спасибо, здесь нашёл,то что искал
http://andsemenoff.narod.ru/programming/wpf/BackgroundWorker_page1.html

Answer (score 3):

Для этих целей обычно применяется подход, основанный на [**BeginInvoke.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190824.aspx)

```
 this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
 {
     // Обновите ваш UI здесь.
 });
```

Comment: здесь нужен делегат а не анонимный метод

Comment: @alvin Разве здесь не создаётся делегат `Action` на лямбда-функцию?

Answer (score 0):

В wpf обычные потоки работают также как и во всём остальном .NET + BackgroundWorker тоже никто не отменял. 
Обновление визуальной части производится добавлением метода в очередь основного потока.

```
control.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new fDelegate(f), null);

...
private delegate void fDelegate();
private void f(){
}
```

Comment: Но зачем определять `fDelegate`? В BCL уже есть `System.Action`.