# Выполнение подключения к серверу и запросов в другом потоке

Tags: wpf, c#

Здраствуйте! Много раз задавал подобный вопрос:

[Действия в другом потоке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/106602/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5);

[Создание потока на c# wpf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/91441).

но так и не понял, как это сделать.

```
Мне надо выполнять действия (подключение к серверу и выполнение запросов) в другом потоке, перечитал вроде много, но что-то ничего не получается. Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать (подробно, если не сложно), что именно надо писать, чтоб указанный мною метод выполнялся в новом потоке?
-------------------------------Олег Нечитайло
Добавил пространство имён
using System.Threading.Tasks; к первому
Во втором пишет "Невозможно преобразовать "лямбда-выражение" к типу "System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority", поскольку он не является делегатом"
Пример приблизительно такой, только потом вместо этого будет подключение к серверу
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
                {
                    txtProgress.Content += "+";  
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                }
            }, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

выполнение действия в новом потоке:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
{
    //писать действия здесь
});
```

Для обновления UI из другого потока необходимо использовать

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
{  
    //обновление UI
}, null);
```